# Git: How to rebase remote to a branch master

Tags: git

I have created a remote branch from a remote master. After the branch was created, changes were committed to the remote master. How do I rebase the remote branch to the remote master to pick these changes up? Here are the remote branches:

```
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/features/myFeature
  origin/master
```

Here is what I tried:

```
git checkout origin/features/myFeature
git rebase master
git push origin origin/features/myFeature
```

Here is the error message I got:

```
git push origin origin/features/myFeature
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done
To ssh://serverURL:port/path/to/repo
 ! [remote rejected] origin/features/myFeature -> origin/features/myFeature (can not create new references)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://serverURL:port/path/to/repo'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should create a local branch to rebase first:

```
git checkout -b myFeature --track origin/features/myFeature
```

Then you can rebase it on top of master

```
git rebase master
```

And you would need to force push it back to origin, since its history is different after rebase

```
git push -f origin myFeature
```

(make sure nobody else had already cloned and started working on '`myFeature`')

Comment: That all makes perfect sense. However, I get the same error. I started over by deleting my local branches. I tried changing your "git push -f origin myFeature" above to "git push -f origin origin/features/myFeature". But, no luck.

Comment: @DooDah what version of git are you using? What does `git branch -a` returns? (especially after you did delete your local branches) What does `git config push.default` returns?

Comment: fwiw, the way I am solving this is, to do a cherry pick, and then a git --ammend.

Comment: @DooDah but you still need to `git push --force` the updated branch, right?

Comment: @DooDah in that case, I would be interested in your solution: you can pst an answer (and even accept it as the official one): you can answer your own question.

Comment: This slipped by me. I will answer this on Monday. FWIW, I did not share that Gerrit is also involved, though, I am not sure that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be doing git push origin features/myFeature. 'can not create new references' usually means the branch name is wrongly specified, and git cannot create a new branch for you